# Split and Join with special symbol

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I need your help, I created a spreadsheet and I managed to split data separated by a special symbol, but now that I put a lot of raw data my formula is not working and I don't understand why.

This is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uHhyZkyasGkwVVbMheQqXAAOVoZHH_Al6SOgk-JUxbE/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

My formula is this one:

```
=iferror(ARRAYFORMULA({SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(
 IF('Data rearranged'!A3:A<>"", "♥"&'Data rearranged'!A3:A&"♦"&'Data rearranged'!B3:B&"♦"&'Data rearranged'!C3:C&"♦"&'Data rearranged'!D3:D&"♦"&'Data rearranged'!E3:E, ), 
 LEN(REGEXREPLACE(""&'Data rearranged'!F3:F, "[^]+", )))), "♥")), "♦"),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("", 1, 'Data rearranged'!F3:F), "")),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("", 1, 'Data rearranged'!G3:G), "")),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("", 1, 'Data rearranged'!H3:H), "")),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("", 1, 'Data rearranged'!I3:I), ""))}),"")
```

Everything else is working fine, except the data that is supposed to be shown in the Courses area. I guess there is something with the special symbol but I can't figure out what it is.

I would appreciate any help on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is 12 missing rows in column **G** by having **`3`** instead of [image: 0] at the beginning of an array:

[image: 0]

this will output **188** rows instead of **200** and causing the error

Comment: Hi player0, thank you so much for your help. You're right.
I changed the data now I take the data from the colum FTE Wks: .6525.22.6520
But the problem is that sometimes I have a zero at the end, how could I remove that zero to match only .6525.22.652 with course code 281138  ?

Comment: you can use regex to get rid of the trailing zero. example: `=REGEXREPLACE("1230", "0$", )`